# antd RadioButton not checked programatically

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using antd, I have a simple RadioGroup composed of three RadioButtons. Everything works I expect.

Additionally, I defined a button which is supposed to clear the selected button and revert the RadioGroup to the default. It is not working. The underlying data is OK, but the default RadioButton is not visually checked.

The rightmost RadioButton is the default. Selecting either of the other two and pressing the Clear button does not check the rightmost RadioButton.

I have looked at this issue for days and do not see my error. The code is a bit noisy because a database is invovled.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-moore-xni4b)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Radio } from 'antd';
import { ConsoleLog } from './consoleLog';
const RadioGroup = Radio.Group;
const App = () => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(false);
  const initFilters = {
    wireSizeId: { displayValue: '', type: 'num', dbKey: '' },
    colorId: { displayValue: '', type: 'num', dbKey: '' },
    insulationId: { displayValue: '', type: 'num', dbKey: '' },
    wireTypeId: { displayValue: '', type: 'num', dbKey: '' },
    solidStranded: { displayValue: '', type: 'num', dbKey: null },
    copperAlum: { displayValue: '', type: 'num', dbKey: null },
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilters(initFilters);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (filters) {
      console.log('e1', filters);
  }}, [filters]);
  const handleClearFilters = () => {
    console.log('clear1', filters);
    setFilters(initFilters);
  };
  const handleCheckbox = (props) => {
    console.log('checkbox', filters);
    console.log('checkbox', props.target.name, props.target.value, props.target.id);
        let updated = {};
        updated[props.target.name] =
             { displayValue: props.target.id, type: 'num', dbKey: props.target.value };
        console.log(updated);
    setFilters({...filters, ...updated});
  };
  return (
    (filters?<Fragment>
   <ConsoleLog>Render</ConsoleLog>
      <div>
        <ConsoleLog>Radio {filters['solidStranded'].dbKey}</ConsoleLog>
        <RadioGroup
          name='solidStranded'
          onChange={handleCheckbox}
          defaultValue=''
          >
          <Radio
            value='0'
            id='Solid'
            checked={filters['solidStranded'].dbKey === '0'}
            >
            Solid
          </Radio>
          <Radio
            value='1'
            id='Stranded'
            checked={filters['solidStranded'].dbKey === '1'}
            >
            Stranded
          </Radio>
          <Radio
            value=''
            id='none'
            checked={filters['solidStranded'].dbKey === null}
          >
            None
          </Radio>
        </RadioGroup>
      </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={handleClearFilters} >
              Clear Filters
            </button>
          </div>
    </Fragment>:null)
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value` in `RadioGroup` instead `checked` attribute, value must be not null-able

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { Radio } from "antd";

const RadioGroup = Radio.Group;

const App = () => {
  const initFilters = {
    wireSizeId: { displayValue: "", type: "num", dbKey: "" },
    colorId: { displayValue: "", type: "num", dbKey: "" },
    insulationId: { displayValue: "", type: "num", dbKey: "" },
    wireTypeId: { displayValue: "", type: "num", dbKey: "" },
    solidStranded: { displayValue: "", type: "num", dbKey: "-1" }, // change
    copperAlum: { displayValue: "", type: "num", dbKey: null }
  };
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(initFilters);

  const handleClearFilters = () => {
    setFilters(initFilters);
  };

  const handleCheckbox = (props) => {
    setFilters({
      ...filters,
      solidStranded: {
        // change
        displayValue: props.target.id,
        type: "num",
        dbKey: props.target.value
      }
    });
  };
  // the ternary operator isn't necessary now.
  return filters ? (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <RadioGroup
          name="solidStranded"
          onChange={handleCheckbox}
          value={filters["solidStranded"].dbKey} // change
        >
          <Radio value="0" id="Solid">
            Solid
          </Radio>
          <Radio value="1" id="Stranded">
            Stranded
          </Radio>
          <Radio value="-1" id="none">
            None
          </Radio>
        </RadioGroup>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClearFilters}>Clear Filters</button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  ) : null;
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/chekbox-example-8vh07?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much, especially all your effort placing the corrected code on codesandbox. You saved me from craziness.